# Multiple PHP Else If Statements Only Returning First Condition Even When Others Are Met

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, woocommerce

Trying to add shipping insurance based on cart total in woocommerce with a multiple else if function. It seems only the first else if statement is working even when cart total is over $100. What am I missing?

```
    $insurance_fee = 0;
$chosen_methods = WC()->session->get( 'USPS_Simple' );
$chosen_shipping = $chosen_methods[0]; {

    if ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total  >= 50  ) { 
            $insurance_fee = 2.05; 
    } else if ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total  >= 100  ) { 
            $insurance_fee = 2.45; 
    } else if ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total  >= 200  ) { 
            $insurance_fee = 4.60; 
    } else if ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total  >= 300  ) { 
            $insurance_fee = 5.50; 
    } else if ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total  >= 400  ) { 
            $insurance_fee = 6.40; 
    } else if ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total  >= 500  ) { 
            $insurance_fee = 7.30; 
    }
}

//The fallback $insurance_fee value of 0 will be used if none of the conditions are met
$woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Shipping Insurance', $insurance_fee, true, '' );
```

[Shipping insurance should return $2.45 since cart total is > $100](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91fCD.png)

Comment: That's how else if works...  If it doesn't match the above condition and it matches this one..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first conditional block satisfies the criteria (if cart total is > $100, it's also > $50).  Since the second block is an "else if", it will not be entered if the first condition is met.  Try reversing the order of the conditions.

Comment: DOH! Of course it's something so simple. Thanks for helping a noob

Comment: No problem @ZachToth please mark the answer as correct if you deem it so.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add a <= for the statements. 
Like this:

```
 if ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total  >= 50 && $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total < 100 ) { 
        $insurance_fee = 2.05; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the default behavior of `if else if`. When meets a condition, next conditions will never be evaluated as TRUE.

If you want to meet more than one conditions you can use `if` instead of `if else if`.